# How to make a child powershell process on node

Tags: node.js, powershell

I'm trying to have a spawned Powershell process on Windows with NodeJS, which i can send some commands, and the the output. I've did that with the stdio configuration form the parent node process, but i want to have it separated, and i cant achieve any of this to correctly work.

In this code, i was hoping to get the output of $PSTableVersion powershell variable on the psout.txt file, but it gets never written.

The simple code is:

```js
var
  express = require('express'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var err = fs.openSync('pserr.txt', 'w');
var out = fs.openSync('psout.txt', 'w');
var writer = fs.createWriteStream(null, {
  fd: fs.openSync('psin.txt', 'w')
});

var child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["-Command", "-"], {
  detached: true,
  stdio: [writer, out, err]
});

writer.write('$PSTableVersion\n');
writer.end();

child.unref();

// just wait
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
```

### Update

I've tried with the code on this node github issue tracker: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8795
It seems calling .NET vs calling native executable are different things...

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I have custom powershell cmdlets which i wan to interact with on my ExpressJS app. Also, i want to have always 'live' the powershell process to receive some input, and give the "calculated output".

Comment: [PowerShell Web Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831611.aspx) may be an alternate way to get there.